# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

me sale este problema
`Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046`

Podrian brindarme alguna guia?

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('db_conn1.php');


if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['cellphone']) && !empty($_POST['message'])){

    $name = $_POST['name'];

    $email= $_POST['email'];

    $cellphone = $_POST['cellphone'];

    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $result="INSERT INTO consult(name,email,cellphone,message) VALUES (:name,:email,:cellphone,:message)";
    $pdo=$conn->prepare($result);
    $pdo->bindParam(":name",$name);
    $pdo->bindParam(":email",$email);
    $pdo->bindParam(":cellphone",$cellphone);
    $pdo->bindParam(":message",$message);
   

    //si la data ha sido insertada exitosamente

    if($pdo->execute()){

         echo "Registro exitoso!";

     }else{

        echo "error de registro, intente nuevamente";

    }



}
```

---

este es el db_conn1.php

```
<?php

try{

    $databaseHost='localhost';
    $databaseUsername='root';
    $databaseName='db_consult';
    $databasePassword='';

    $conn=new PDO("mysql:host=$databaseHost;$databaseUsername;$databasePassword;dbname=$databaseName");

}catch(PDOException $error){
    echo "!Error de conexión¡" .$error->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Eso es un error al intentar ejecutar alguna consulta con una conexión que no indica qué BD usar. Por favor, edita tu pregunta nuevamente y añade el contenido de `db_conn1.php`. Como texto, tal y como hiciste con este código. Sin incluir las credenciales reales ;)

Answer (score 0):

En la línea

```
$conn=new PDO(
    "mysql:host=$databaseHost;$databaseUsername;$databasePassword;dbname=$databaseName"
);
```

Entendería que estás usando el primer parámetro para proveer el dsn pero estás incluyendo el usuario y la contraseña sin más. En ninguna parte de [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) dice que esa construcción de PDO funcione.

Lo que debería funcionar es algo como

```
$conn=new PDO(
    "mysql:host=$databaseHost;dbname=$databaseName", 
    $databaseUsername, 
    $databasePassword
);
```